# Launching a sip client from a Mobile Browser

Tags: android, ios, webkit, lync, lync-2010

Is there a way to get an href with a sip address to open in a Mobile browser on either iOS or Android like it does on a desktop browser?

I'm using Lync 2010 as my sip client and it won't launch when I click that link in my mobile browser on either phone. I see it make the attempt but Lync doesn't come up like on my desktop.  Both have the client installed and even open in the background.

Here's an example:

```
<a href="sip:lou@lou.com">Lou</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought this would have to be implemented in the OS and the application would then register as able to open links of that type. I don't think any change to settings or to the app would enable this. Unfortunately, I don't see any mobile OS vendors implementing this anytime soon - there just isn't enough traction.

Comment: I was hoping at least with Chrome it would give you the option, like it does on the desktop, to chose to open the link in whatever sip client you have. I guess in the mobile client though, they'd want you to spend money text messaging.